# Changing an Apple ID from one @icloud.com address to another

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

I have an Apple ID which ends with `@icloud.com` and I want to change it to another `@icloud.com`, `@me.com`, or `@mac.com`. I've found [a page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667) which describes how to do that but it seems it doesn't work for me. I turned off two-factor authentication and removed all my devices. But there is no the following option:

> Under your Apple ID, click Change Apple ID.

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you have other email addresses associated with your account?

Comment: No, I had 2 `@icloud.com` aliases but I also deleted them.

Comment: I've just tried with my account and the instructions in the support article linked below.  That only seem to allow you to change your address from me to icloud or vice versa not to a different username before the @.  From reading the article I had assumed it would let you change it to an alias but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple Support page about changing your Apple ID (emphasis added by me):

> If your Apple ID email address ends with @icloud.com, @me.com, or
>   @mac.com, you can only change your email address to another
>   @icloud.com, @me.com, or @mac.com email **that's already associated with
>   your account**.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667

If you created your Apple ID recently with an `@icloud.com` address as identifier, you most probably can't change that. I think the support document I linked to is targeted at users who have old `@me.com` or `@mac.com` addresses that Apple used to issue a long while ago. Or maybe there could be special situations where you actually have two `@icloud.com` addresses associated with one Apple ID as the result of merging two IDs with the help of Apple Support, but those would be rare exceptional cases. For a recently created `@icloud.com` style Apple ID, typically you can't change it.

Comment: Yes, but how can I make them associated with my account? One can get an `@icloud` address when he/she create a new Apple ID or create an alias. I had aliases and I couldn't set any of then as the primary address.

Answer (score 1):

As of Aug, 2019, the situation is still unresolved.

After a conversation with Apple Support it transpired that the ability to change an AppleID that ends with @icloud.com to a mail alias that end in @icloud.com is not implemented.

However, it is possible to do this if your mail alias end in @me.com or @mac.com, which is what [the support article mentioned in the accepted answer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667#appleaddress) refers to.

Apparently, the reason this hasn't been implemented is because this feature hasn't been requested often enough by the users.

If you're affected by this, or if you would like to see this implemented, please visit https://www.apple.com/feedback/icloud.html (Feedback Type: Account) and submit the feedback form to let Apple know that you too would like this feature implemented.